# Paging with ScrollView using directly storyboard instead of creating .xib files

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, storyboard, paging

Sorry in advance, this is a long question but I wanted to explain as good as I can.

I need to implement a walkthrough(first time launch guide) for the project, which will only be shown to user for the first time they launch the app.

I've implemented it by creating a .xib file, where I was just creating a view for each item I need to implement for the walkthrough by creating objects referring to .xib model.

But now I'm required to implement it without using .xib files, where I need to do it via storyboard. This time I've inserted a scrollView, and then I put another view inside it with the objects I'm going to need such as (labels,imageViews,buttons etc.) But it doesn't work, even though I can create all the objects by copying the view right under the scrollView. When I try to expand the width of the scrollView with all the views created so I can do paging, it doesn't create each view next to each other but only shows me the last object(view) in the simulator as they add up vertically, and I can't do no paging.

Now I provide some sample code to show how I try to implement this:

```
import UIKit

class DenemeViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

@IBOutlet weak var repeatingView: UIView!

var viewArray = [UIView]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let temporaryView = repeatingView
    temporaryView?.backgroundColor = .black
    viewArray.append(temporaryView!)

    let temporaryViewTwo = repeatingView
    temporaryViewTwo?.backgroundColor = .blue
    viewArray.append(temporaryViewTwo!)

    pageControl.numberOfPages = viewArray.count
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
    view.bringSubview(toFront: pageControl)

    setupScrollView(items: viewArray)
}

func setupScrollView(items: [UIView]) {
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(items.count), height: view.frame.height)
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

    for i in 0..<items.count {
        items[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        scrollView.addSubview(items[i])
    }
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)
}
}
```

As you can see I first create two different views in viewDidLoad by referring to "repeatingView" which is the outlet of the view inside scrollView on the storyboard. Then I return them in an array and try to implement scrollView's subviews with views.

I was expecting to see the scrollView starting with the view with black background and as I do the paging through right then the view with blue background should appear.

When I run this what I see is only the blue view, and I'm unable to do any paging or scrolling.

[image: Storyboard Hierarchy]

Comment: What about UICollectionView or UIPageViewController

Comment: I also thought about those, like I mentioned I could also do it with .xib file. But since it is advised and requested from my supervisor that I should do it this way, I'm looking for the reason why this implementation doesn't work.

Comment: You only seem to have one `repeatingView`, so you don't have two views. Assigning `repeatingView` to different variables doesn't copy it. The view will just have the last frame and background color that is assigned to it.